# Is there a Symfony register_shutdown_function / destruction equivalent for executing code post-content delivery?

Tags: php, symfony1, shutdown-hook

I need various things to happen after the user has been sent a response, like how register_shutdown_function *used* to work.

I've had a play with sfShutdownPlugin, it just uses register_shutdown_function, I've also had a look at using a destructor (only on an action) but Symfony doesn't seem to like that too much and the postExecute method still happens before content is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how the filter chain works - can you find a point where the response has been sent but execution is still running? If so, you should be able to add your own filter to the chain at this point.

Not sure this'll quite do what you want though - don't think the browser will see it as finished, so the spinner will keep going even if content has loaded and is shown, and won't it delay document.ready etc?

The sfStorage classes use shutdown stuff i think - might be worth looking at what they do.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not sure it's worth my effort if it's likely the browser will still think it's unfinished. I'm sure I remember register_shutdown_function working like this, perhaps only in PHP4.

Comment: register shutdown will work as you want. not sure that using symfony filters will. i think sfStorage works properly, think it uses register_shutdown too.